# IDA* search algorithm pseudocode explanation

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star

I'm struggling to implement the IDA* algorithm in Python (i'm a newbie) folowing the [Wikipedia pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA%2a).

Can you explain me what am I supposed to check on this line:

```
if t = ∞ then return NOT_FOUND
```

What do they mean with infinite? The same value that I have here?

```
min := ∞
```

If you have other pseudcode sources I will be happier!

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

it means infinite. Many object oriented languages provide a "infinite" value, and where it does not exist, you can replace infinite with maximun value of the variable. (and minus infinite with lower bound)

in python you can do

```
test = float("inf")
```

Comment: Ok, but my question was: what do I have to check there? I cannot understand from the pseudocode..

Comment: it is a "yes" to your question, think about infine as a flag that say you have found NO node (or better, you have found no node with less than INFINITE cost). Note that an overflow will cause the value to become infinite, so normally code won't break

Answer (score 1):

I think lesto's answer just says how to implement and doesn't answer *"but my question was: what do I have to check there?"*, so I answer this part that I think the OP needs to know.

IDA* in two sentences:

1. Perform A*, and suppose the nodes below the depth limit have no child
2. If succeed : finish ...   
   else : 
        perform A* (again) with new depth limit (the minimum `f` that was above depth limit)

Now let's see this again:

```
if t = ∞ then return NOT_FOUND
```

The only way t equals infinity is that nodes have a `f` value that is less than the limit but there is no goal state among them and the node with maximum `f` has no child too. (Note if a node has a successor for sure min won't be infinity)